# jqGrid getData from all page

Tags: jqgrid

I need to getdata from all pages in jqgrid
 for which below code dont work

```
var allRowsInGrid = $('#grid').jqGrid('getRowData');
```

so tried this:

```
var allRowsInGrid = $("#grid").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'data');
```

which is working fine but all new data like edit done on any editable field is getting lost

i saw below link for similar issue

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3307189/jqgrid-getdata-only-returns-data-for-current-page

please help